# Is there a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe a nephew's wife's mother?

Comment: Human? Female? Related?

Answer (score 2):

Not in English. (Source: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nephew%27s+wife%27s+mother) )